# Where do I place a model file in android studio? and how can I load it from a normal class, not an activity?

Tags: android, file, android-studio

I have tried many different ways to load a model file or even a simple text file in android studio. I have put it in the assets folder but could not read from it because my class is not an activity class. I tried just putting the file with the classes and reading it directly but that didn't work. Most recently I tried reading it in from the res/raw folder (raw was created.) but my application still can't find the file. Here is my latest attempt which i got from another answer on stack that has not worked, because it still can't find the model.

```
String file = "res/raw/filteredsvmmodel2.model";
InputStream in this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

I am stuck on this problem and any method, import, library or anything else that can solve the problem of reading a simple file will help.

Comment: Try reading from the /asset folder https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have put it in the assets folder but could not read from it because my class is not an activity class.

Pass a `Context` to your class (e.g., in its constructor). What `Context` you use depends a bit on where you are creating your instances of this class and how long you intend to hold onto those instances. You might use the `Context` that triggered the creation of your class' instance (e.g., `Activity`, `Service`). Or, you might call `getApplicationContext()` on one of those, then pass in that `Context` to your constructor.

> Most recently I tried reading it in from the res/raw folder (raw was created.) but my application still can't find the file.

Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device. You read in a raw resource by calling `openRawResource()` on a `Resources` object. You get one of those by calling `getResources()` on a `Context`.

Comment: What if I am not calling the class from an activity. Is there another way to pass an activity or context.

Comment: @Brock: You should have a `Context`. If this work is being triggered by an `Activity`, that is your `Context`. If this work is being triggered by a `Service`, that is your `Context`. If this work is being triggered by a `BroadcastReceiver`, you are passed a `Context` in `onReceive()`. If this work is being triggered by a `ContentProvider`, call `getContext()`. If this work is being triggered by an `Application`, that is your `Context`. There are no other scenarios that I can think of in Android app development.